# Proving $\mathbb { E } \left[ ( f ( x ) - \mathbb { E } [ f ( x ) ] ) ^ { 2 } \right] = \mathbb { E } \left[f(x)^{2}\right]-\mathbb{E}[f(x)]^{2}$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am struggling a bit proving the following,

$$\mathbb { E } \left[ ( f ( x ) - \mathbb { E } [ f ( x ) ] ) ^ { 2 } \right] = \mathbb { E } \left[ f(x) ^ { 2 } \right] - \mathbb { E } [ f(x) ] ^ { 2 }$$

This is what I have done so far (very basic, just expanded the square)

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb { E } \left[ ( f ( x ) - \mathbb { E } [ f ( x ) ] ) ^ { 2 } \right] &= \mathbb { E } \left[ f ( x )^{2} - f( x ) \mathbb { E } [ f ( x ) ] ) - f( x ) \mathbb 
  { E } [ f ( x ) ] ) + \mathbb{ E } [ f ( x ) ] ^ { 2 } \right] \\
  &= \mathbb { E } \left[  f ( x )^{2} - 2f( x ) \mathbb { E } [ f ( x ) ] ) + \mathbb{ E } [ f ( x ) ]  ^ { 2 } \right]
\end{align*}

this is where I kind of get stuck. I know that expectations are linear which means that I can do something like this using additivity and homogeneity

$$\mathbb { E } \left[ ( f ( x )^{2} \right] - 2\mathbb{ E } \left[f( x ) \mathbb { E } [ f ( x ) ] ) \right] + \mathbb{ E } \left[\mathbb { E } [ f ( x ) ]  ^ { 2 } \right]$$

but I'm not sure where to go after this.

How do I finish this proof?

What am I missing?

Comment: Well is $x$ a *real number* or *random variable*? This is why there is the convention of using capital letters $X$ to denote RVs and lower-case for the values they take on: $X=x$. To be sure, $\mathbb{E}(f(x))=f(x)$ for any function $f$ and any real $x$ since there is no randomness at play, but $\mathbb{E}(f(X))$ is a “true” expectation since there is randomness involved.

Comment: By linearity, the second term is $2E[f(x)]^2$ and since $E[f(x)]$ is a constant, the last one is $(E[f(x)])^2$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 My bad, I should have been more specific with whether or not x is a real number or random variable, I'll edit it. But to answer your question $x$ is real number that is determined by a probability distribution if that makes sense? $\mathbb { E } [ f ( x ) ] = \sum _ { x } P ( x ) f ( x )$

Comment: @JDub the more conventional notation is $\mathbb{E}(f(X))=\sum_x f(x)\mathbb{P}(X=x)$ compare to, if $c$ is some constant, then $$\mathbb{E}_X(f(c))=\sum_x f(c) \mathbb{P}(X=x)=f(c)\sum_x \mathbb{P}(X=x)=f(c)\cdot 1=f(c),$$ do you see the difference and how the upper-lower case convention is used signify whether randomness is at play? Just an FYI, because you might see this later, and personally I think it is very helpful to internalize.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Yes, the difference is very clear. The notation I was using was one that I copied out of a textbook that I have been reading but the conventional notation that you provided is much better, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$**Hints:** Since $\E\left[f(x)\right]^2$ is a constant, we have $\E\left[\E[f(x)]^2\right] = \E[f(x)]^2$ (remember, the expected value of a constant is itself). Also, since $\color{blue}{\E[f(x)]}$ is a constant, we can pull it outside the expectation to get that $\E\left[f(x)\color{blue}{\E[f(x)]}\right] = \color{blue}{\E[f(x)]} \E[f(x)] = \E\left[f(x)\right]^2$.

Comment: Thanks, it clicked when you mentioned that the expected value of a constant is itself. As intuitive as that is I guess it went over my head!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\mathbb{E}[f(x)]$ is a real number and as you said, expectations are linear. So, what is $\mathbb{E}[f(x)\mathbb{E}[f(x)]]$ equal to?